# How to include Oracle Instant Client in airflow docker containers?

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I am using [puckel's airflow docker images](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) to run an airflow app that is going to extract data from an Oracle database and pass it to another database. I have provided environment variables for the database connection in the [docker-composeCeleryExecutor](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/docker-compose-CeleryExecutor.yml) that look like this:

```
AIRFLOW_CONN_ORACLE_FLXP=oracle://oracle_user:XXXXXXXXXXXX@1.1.1.1:1521?encoding=UTF-8&nencoding=UTF-8&threaded=False&events=False&mode=sysdba&purity=new
```

I want to run a query in the oracle database in a DAG task using the OracleOperator like this:

```
t1 = OracleOperator(
    task_id='run_query',
    sql=query,
    oracle_conn_id='oracle_flxp',
    dag=dag)
```

However, the task is failing with the following error:

```
{{models.py:1788}} ERROR - DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".
```

I figured, that I might need to install the oracle instant client in my airflow container or in a separate container. I have already tried to create [this oracle instant client image](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleInstantClient/dockerfiles/12.2.0.1/Dockerfile) and added it to the docker-composeCeleryExecutor in this way:

```
    oracle:
        image: oracle/instantclient:12.2.0.1
        command: sqlplus -v
    webserver:
        depends_on:
            - oracle
        ...
```

But the error is still the same. Also, when I run the docker-compose, the oracle container is initializing, but after a second exiting again, printing the line:

```
docker-airflow_oracle_1 exited with code 0
```

I was actually expecting that airflow would be already set up for connecting to oracle databases. Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Acutally, you will need build you own docker images to add oracle database client. 3 Steps:
1. download the latest oracle db client 
2. add those file into your previously docker base image 
3. try it again.

in the 2nd step, you will need write Dockerfile to rebuild. it may likes following

FROM puckel/docker-airflow
ADD oracle-instantclient*.rpm /tmp/
...
...